# What's the difference between "Activity" and "Newest"?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes it seems no difference between "Activity" and "Newest", the question under these two tags are all arranged in timely order. But sometimes, I simply can't understand "Activity" tag. For example, under a user's profile-favorites-activity, I can't understand how they arrange the sequence.

Comment: "Newest" sorts by when the question was created, and "Activity" sorts by when the last activity (like editing or commenting) was performed on it.  I think.  Creating a question counts as "activity", so sometimes these 2 may not be different.