# What the heck is going on with the "newest" question filter on the profile page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, profile-page, sorting

[Link to my profile page *newest* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1986871/chris-cirefice?tab=questions&sort=newest).

Yes, I've read [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223206/whats-the-difference-between-activity-and-newest). I thought I already knew the answer:

- *activity* is most recent activity (answers, comments, edits)
- *newest* is ordered by when the *question* was asked

And the comment on that answer seems to verify that information. [Another older Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29400/whats-the-difference-between-recent-and-newest-sort-options-in-my-user-page) is similar (although the "recent" filter changed to "activity"), and the answer makes sense. However, that's not what I'm seeing in my profile.

*Activity* seems to only track *new answers*, *edits to answers*, and maybe something else? In any case, it makes sense and is ordered properly.

*Newest* seems to track edits to the Q/A, new answers, but not comments (maybe??). The weird thing is, it's not even sorted in order! The "newest" filter, I would assume, is the `created_at` timestamp for the *question*, and nothing else. But that's not the case, and it's not even sorted chronologically. See the image below from my Stack Overflow profile:

[image: "newest" filter broken?]

So, in essence, "newest" seems to be completely broken, or I just have a horrible misunderstanding of how it's supposed to function. But it doesn't seem like it should function like this... they should at *least* be sorted in chronological order. **What the heck is going on here?**

PS - I tagged this as [bug] because I think it actually might be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's working as it should.

These are *your* newest questions and so they are ordered according to when you asked them. That's why the part in red circles is misleading (that's just the last activity). I did have a look at the top questions and they are in chronological order (25 days ago, 1 year 1 month, 2 years 1 month, 2 years 6 months etc.).

Comment: Ah good point. I guess I should have thought more about the question order rather than the timestamps for the "last activity" date... hmmm, well this seems like a UX issue. Those dates are very misleading if you don't know what they mean. I thought they were the question post date, but it's the last activity date... maybe there should be a header like "last activity" for those timestamps? I don't know.

Comment: It shouldn't be showing the last activity date though. See on a site's main questions page that the active tab shows the last activity date, but the newest page shows the actual date they were asked.

Comment: @curiousdannii The question is about sorting and it is sorted correctly, i. e. in chronological order. If you feel *newest* shouldn't display the last activity date, maybe start a feature request? This has been raised in the past, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260824/377968) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266951/377968).